# Delphi TStrings.SaveToFile

Tags: delphi, d

Проблема в TStrings.SaveToFile, на одном компьютере файл создается, на другом нет. `SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + FName)` 
Может Windows блокировать создание ?
Стоит копать в сторону Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

> `StringList.SaveToFile('c:\windows\temp\'+FName)`

Во-первых, в Windows 10 папка `c:\windows\temp\` является системной, и не доступна обычным пользователям.

Во-вторых, папки `c:\windows\` может вообще не существовать. Windows может быть установлена в другое место.

Гарантированный способ получить путь к папке для временных файлов - переменная среды `%temp%` и winapi `GetTempPath`.

Должно быть: `StringList.SaveToFile('%temp%\'+FName)`

Comment: Попробовал как вы описали, на одной машине лог создается, на другой не как.  Даже так попробовал `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + FName`

Answer (score 0):

TStringList имеет ограничение на работу с очень большими файлами, если лог будет большым, то вполне возможно что будет генерироваться ошибка Out of memory или просто лог не будет сохранятся. Попробуйте переписать с использованием TFileStream.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел в чем проблема. Сжимали проект через upx.exe, так вот по дороге сжатия что-то терялось, связи с этим и не отрабатывал тстринг. Есть какой-то другой компрессор ?

Comment: Крайне странная причина. Уж если упаковщик корёжит файл, то вряд ли так, что одно (сомнительное) место перестанет работать